# Why are the random samples drawn from my custom distribution not following the pdf?

Tags: python, statistics, histogram, distribution, scipy.stats

I have created a custom distribution using scipy's rv_continuous method. I am trying to create the energy distribution of an electron produced by beta decay. Given its pdf:

[image: Expression giving shape of kinetic energy distribution from Fermi Theory]

Which I took from: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Nuclear/beta2.html#c1

I define my distribution:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import rv_continuous 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

class beta_decay(rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self, x):
        return (22.48949986*np.sqrt(x**2 + 2*x*0.511)*((0.6-x)**2)*(x+0.511))

# create distribution from 0 --> Q value = 0.6 
beta = beta_decay(a=0, b= 0.6)

# plot pdf 
x = np.linspace(0,0.6)
plt.plot(x, beta.pdf(x))
plt.show()

# random sample the distribution and plot histogram 
random = beta.rvs(size =100)
plt.hist(random)
plt.show()
```

Where x = KE, Q = 0.6, C = 22.48... (found by integrating the above expression between 0 --> Q and setting equal to 1 to normalize), and I disregard the Fermi function F(Z',KEe) in the above eqn.

When I graph the pdf, it looks right: [image]

However, when I try to draw random samples from it using .rvs(), the value they take are massively peaked towardes the RHS, not under the peak of the pdf as I'd expect:
[image]

Ultimately, my code needs to sample the distribution to get the KE of an electron released by beta decay. Why is my histogram so wrong?

Comment: Please post code as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: It looks to me like your PDF is just wrong. Eyeballing it, the area under the curve in that graph looks a lot lower than 1, and the expression in your `_pdf` method is going to grow rapidly past x=0.6.

Comment: "and I disregard the Fermi function F(Z',KEe) in the above eqn" - why did you do that?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Hello, posted as code now - sorry! I will try and add the fermi function - my understand was it is just a correction factor - at this point, I just want something that works (ie can I define a distribution and sample from it correctly) rather than physical accuracy. I only want my pdf to be defined between 0 -> 0.6 , since 0.6 is the max energy available from the radioactive decay. Perhaps my normalisation of the pdf was incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your PDF is defined in a wrong way, it is not normalized. After I normalized it and made proper histogram, it seems to work fine

Code (Win10 x64, Anaconda Python 3.7)

```
#%%
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as integrate

from scipy.stats import rv_continuous

def bd(x):
    return (22.48949986*np.sqrt(x**2 + 2*x*0.511)*((0.6-x)**2)*(x+0.511))

a = 0.0
b = 0.6

norm = integrate.quad(bd, a, b) # normalization integral
print(norm)

class beta_decay(rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self, x):
        return bd(x)/norm[0]

# create Q distribution in the [0...0.6] interval
beta = beta_decay(a = a, b = b)

# plot pdf
x = np.linspace(a, b)
plt.plot(x, beta.pdf(x))
plt.show()

# sample from pdf
r = beta.rvs(size = 10000)
plt.hist(r, range=(a, b), density=True)
plt.show()
```

And plots

[image]

sampling

[image]

Comment: thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. And you've shown me an entire world of integration with scipy I didn't know existed :D. Accepted your answer.